# After migration Sharepoint doesn't tell that the page is checked out

Tags: 2010, master-page, migration, ribbon

After we did a migration to a portal we found a weird behavior which I need your help in
we migrated the masterpages manually and added the ribbon code and all of the placeholders

the issue is that when a page is checked out to another user the ribbon tabs (Browse,page,publish) aren't displayed and when you click on the edit page icon it just refreshes and nothing happens

there's is no tabs to select to override check out, also there's even no status message to tell the user that the page is checked out to another user

I have a feeling that I forgot a placeholder or something in the master page which is responsible of this behavior

So please help
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues told me that he installed a patch or something which keeps the ribbon always shown (sorry no link) which eventually solved the issue